# Ajax response есть, а данных в базе нет

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Есть форма обратной связи. заполняем 4 поля, отправляем и без перезагрузки страницы получаем в ответ надпись, что форма отправлена. Без ajax все работает. Ajax прикручиваю, запрос формируется, отправляется, получаю ответ обратно, но данные из формы не заносятся в базу. Т.е. ошибок явных нет, в базе ничего не появляется, надписи об успешном выполнении нет.

Думаю проблема в изъятии данных из POST или в записи в базу, хочу вашего мнения. Валидации и перехвата ошибок нет (да я плох, но пока так).

На скриншоте видно(консоль Firefox), что скрипт отрабатывает, данные уходят.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель:

```
class zForm(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Имя", null=True, blank=True)
email = models.CharField(verbose_name='email', max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
subject = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Тема", null=True, blank=True)
message = models.TextField(max_length=2056, verbose_name="Сообщение", null=True, blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), verbose_name="Дата сообщения", null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta():
    db_table = "Форма связи"
    verbose_name = "Форма связи"
```

HTML:

```
 <section id="six">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <h3>Контакты</h3>
                                    <p>Отправьте мне сообщения по форме ниже или свяжитесь со мной через социальные сети.</p>
{% if form_ok %}
 <div id="results"></div>
{% endif %}
                                    <form method="post" id="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="row uniform">
                                            <div class="6u 12u(xsmall)"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Имя" required/></div>
                                            <div class="6u 12u(xsmall)"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row uniform">
                                                <div class="12u">
                                                    <div class="select-wrapper">
                                                        <select name="subject" id="subject" style="font-style:Italic;color:#aaaaaa;" required aria-required="true">
                                                            <option value="">- Тема -</option>
                                                            <option value="Вопросы">Вопросы</option>
                                                            <option value="Сотрудничество">Сотрудничество</option>
                                                            <option value="Нашел ошибку">Нашел ошибку</option>
                                                            <option value="Люблю общаться">Люблю общаться</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row uniform">
                                            <div class="12u"><textarea maxlength="2056" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Сообщение" rows="6" required aria-required="true"></textarea></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row uniform">
                                            <div class="12u">
                                                <ul class="actions">
                                                    <li><input type="submit" class="special" value="Отправить" /></li>
                                                    <li><input type="reset" value="Отчистить" /></li>
                                                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="demo-human" name="demo-human" required aria-required="true">
                                                    <label for="demo-human">Я человек, а не робот</label></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </section>
```

Вьюха:

```
def create_post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST.get('name', '')
    email = request.POST.get('email', '')
    subject = request.POST.get('subject', '')
    message = request.POST.get('message', '')
    response_data = {}
    a = zForm.objects.create(
        name=name,
        email=email,
        subject=subject,
        message=message
    )
    a.save()
    response_data['form_ok'] = 1
    response_data['result'] = "Сообщение отправлено!"
    response_data.update(csrf(request))
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
else:
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn`t happening"}),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

JS ajax(только рабочая часть):

```
    $(function() {
    $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form submited!")
        create_post();
    });

    function create_post() {
        console.log("create post is working!")
        var name = $('#name').val()
        var email = $('#email').val()
        var subject = $('#subject').val()
        var message = $('#message').val()
        $.ajax({
            url: 'create_post/',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'name': name, 'email': email, 'subject': subject, 'message': message },
            success: function(json) {
                $('#name').val('')
                $('#email').val('')
                $('#subject').val('')
                $('#message').val('');
                $('#results').html("<b>"+json.result+"</b>");
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                $('#results').html("<div>oops! error: "+errmsg+"</div>");
                console.log(xhr.status + ": " +xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    };
// This function gets cookie with a given name
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    /*
    The functions below will create a header with csrftoken
    */

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    function sameOrigin(url) {
        // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
        // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
        var host = document.location.host; // host + port
        var protocol = document.location.protocol;
        var sr_origin = '//' + host;
        var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
        // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
        return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
            (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
            // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
            !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
                // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
                // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
                // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А `Response`-то в той же консоли Firefox какой?

Comment: возвращает страницу , но без надписи, что все ок

Comment: возвращает страницу , но без надписи, что все прошло успешно , а так же в базе ничего не появляется, может на моменте записи в базу возникает ошибка и процесс  прерывается? @andreymal

Comment: Какую именно страницу-то?

Comment: @andreymal дык ту , с которой форма заводилась. В этом же и суть)

Comment: В том коде, который вы привели, это невозможно. Здесь create_post всегда возвращает только json. Вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: @andreymal я предельно с Вами откровенен. Возможно, я просто не понимаю что пишу. На корневом юрл страница с формой , по кнопке сабмит срабатывает функция, которая пересылает на юрл create_post/   - там висит вьюха и возвращая json - все это на странице коревого юрл с начальной формой

Comment: Ну вот и покажите этот json, который должен присутствовать на вкладке `Response` в этой вашей консоли Firefox

Comment: @andreymal там HTML код возвращенной страницы(весь) , а вместо {% csrftoken %} записано value='...многобукоф'

Comment: Ну вот это невозможно, потому что приведённый create_post возвращает только json ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Вы всё ещё что-то не договраиваете, а что — даже фиг знает. Может, в `urls.py` опечатка и ссылка `/create_post/` ведёт НЕ на вьюху `create_post`?

Comment: @andreymal Вы абсолютно правы! Я ошибся в юрлах. Столько горения из-за невнимательности... спасибо.Вы можете дать ответ на вопрос чтобы я засчитал Вам его?

Comment: Не могу, опечаткам не положено быть на ruSO ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯